# GetMedia does not return payload with AWS MKV tags?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm trying to create my own stream parser using the Kinesis Video Stream library. I'd like to parse the fragments and then write an .mkv to disk. Per the example, I'm trying to use the FragmentMetadataVisitor to get the next fragment number to do a subsequent GetMediaRequest. Debugging, it looks like none of the MkvElements contain "TAG" metadata. Also, looking at the source code, it looks like FragmentMetadataVistior ignores the AWS tags:

```
       public void visit(MkvDataElement dataElement) throws MkvElementVisitException {
            if (mkvTagProcessor.isPresent()) {
                if (MkvTypeInfos.TAGNAME.equals(dataElement.getElementMetaData().getTypeInfo())) {
                    tagName = getMkvElementStringVal(dataElement);
                } else if (MkvTypeInfos.TAGSTRING.equals(dataElement.getElementMetaData().getTypeInfo())) {
                    tagValue = getMkvElementStringVal(dataElement);
                }
                if (tagName != null && tagValue != null) {
                    // Only process non-internal tags
                    if (!tagName.startsWith(AWS_KINESISVIDEO_TAGNAME_PREFIX)) {
                        mkvTagProcessor.get().process(new MkvTag(tagName, tagValue), currentFragmentMetadata);
                    }
                    // Empty the values for new tag
                    tagName = null;
                    tagValue = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using the BasicMkvTagProcessor  to process the tags. However, debugging, the process(tag, metadata) method never gets called. I'm using the FragmentMetadataVisitor like so:

```
 StreamingMkvReader streamingMkvReader =
                StreamingMkvReader.createDefault(new InputStreamParserByteSource(result.getPayload()));

        try(WritableByteChannel channel = FileChannel.open(generatePath(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND,StandardOpenOption.CREATE)){

            while(streamingMkvReader.mightHaveNext()){
                Optional<MkvElement> nextItem = streamingMkvReader.nextIfAvailable();

                if(nextItem.isEmpty()){
                    return Optional.empty();
                }

                MkvElement item = nextItem.get();

                /*Write to file*/

        } catch(IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create file.", e);
        } catch(MkvElementVisitException e){
            throw new RuntimeException("An error occurred while writing MkvElement to file.");
        }

        return /*new StartSelector for next fragment using fragmentMetadataVisitor.getCurrentFragmentMetadata() to find the last fragment number*/;
    }
```

Given this, is there another class I'm supposed to use to pull the AWS metadata described in the GetMedia documentation? Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

AWS just added the GetClip API which I can use instead.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/API_reader_GetClip.html